# Struts2 jQuery plygin Select box width issues

Tags: jquery, html, struts2, width

I am trying to place 4 jQuery Select boxes in a straight line. So I am placing them inside a table like this:

```
<table>
 <tr><td> <sj:select> <option>......</sj:select> </td>
 <td> <sj:select> <option>......</sj:select> </td>
 <td> <sj:select> <option>......</sj:select> </td></tr> 
</table>
```

The select boxes have option values that are longer.So the select boxes overlap and hence half of each select box becomes invisible. I tried to set the width using `style="width:40px"`. But this dint change the width. But when i set the width using `$("#selectid").width(40);` there is a change in the width. 
I am setting the width of the `<td>` to 40 using `<td width="40">` and the width of the select box also to 40. Some how the width of the select box appears to be very small. Since I am setting the width of the td and that of the select box to the same width, I thought they both would be of same size. I want the size of them to be same. Can some one help me resolve this issue?

PS: I tried to increase the width of the select box. But doing that increases the width of the `<td>` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well since you didn't provide any code, I would put the select boxes in a `div` wrapper and use `CSS` to display it side by side.

Your CSS stylesheet would look like this:

```
select {
   display:inline-block;
   margin-right:10px;
   float:left;
   max-width:100px;
}

div.wrapper {
   min-width:450px;
}
```

All you have to do is display your `select`'s like this, of course with `option`'s

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <select></select>
  <select></select>
  <select></select>
  <select></select>
</div>
```

I guess the main answer to this question is, use that I would use `CSS`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the solution. but I still seem to face the same issue.Basically the issue is 20px mentioned as width to the jquery select box seems to be much smaller than 20px size set as width to the HTML components like div td etc.The difference in size seems to be filled with white space.